# How can I place 5 next to 0 (5 + 0 = 50) instead of just adding 5+0=5 in c?

Tags: c

Do I need to multiply the first number by 10 and then add the 2nd or is there a way in c to lay numbers next to each other in a location.

Comment: are you trying to get a number or a string as a result ?

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you are trying to do? Its not clear from the question.

Comment: please define / show as code what you mean by _numbers_ and _location_: what type of variable? what values?

Comment: "*to lay numbers next to each other in a location*" 1+ for this wording... *lol*

Answer (score 2):

Adding digits using integers and addition:

```
int i1 = 5;
int i2 = 0;
int result = i1 * 10 + i2; /* 50 */
```

Concatenating characters to get a string `"50"`:

```
char c1 = '5';
char c2 = '0';
char result[3];
result[0] = c1;
result[1] = c2;
result[2] = '\0'; /* End of string */
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `+=` concatenating operator in C.

You can [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) those two numbers into a char array. And convert it back to integer using [`strto*`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) function if you need it in integer representation.

Comment: `*printf` / `strto*` is rather overkill

Comment: I suppose an answer needs to be a bit more generic rather than just two single digit numbers.

Comment: Agreed. Anyway some char array manipulations are way more efficient. I think my answer below will get OP started.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only with integers, then use this

```
int a = 5;
int b = 0;
int c = a * 10 + b
```

For the string manupulation

```
 char a = '5';
 char b = '0';
 char c[3];
 snprintf(c, 3, "%c%c", a, b);
 c[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: Note: Usage of `int snprintf(char * s, size_t n, const char * format, ...);` is not correct.  `c[2] = '\0';` not needed.

Comment: sorry made a mistake...Edited it...\0 is something I put as precaution